# ActionRecord modeling: Employee with many managers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

This should be easy. I think I must be getting caught up on naming.

Both a 'manager' and a 'subordinate' (employee) are of class "Person".

Here's what I have:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_manager_assignments
  has_many :managers, :through => :person_manager_assignments
  has_many :subordinates, :through => :person_manager_assignments
end

class PersonManagerAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :subordinate, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => 'person_id'
  has_one :manager, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "id", :primary_key => 'manager_id'
end
```

Which works great for checking and assigning managers.

I'm caught on the part about subordinates. It returns the Person's self, instead of their subordinates:

```
p.subordinates
  Person Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "person_manager_assignments" ON "people"."id" = "person_manager_assignments"."person_id" WHERE "person_manager_assignments"."person_id" = 15973
```

See the bit where in the WHERE clause where it's matching "person_id"? I need that to be "manager_id", but messing with the PersonManagerAssignment associations foreign_key and primary_key values doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your PersonManagerAssignment model look like?

Comment: I've clarified this question further. I basically need to control which ID is being used in that WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is essentially here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

So I think you need this:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :person_manager_assignments
  has_many :managers, :through => :person_manager_assignments
  has_many :subordinate_relationships, :class_name=>"PersonManagerAssignment", :foreign_key=>"manager_id"
  has_many :subordinates, :through => :subordinate_relationships, :source=>:person
end
```

and

```
class PersonManagerAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name=>"Person"
end
```

Rock on.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Had to make the :source on "has_many :subordinates" ":subordinate" and had to keep the PersonManagerAssignment the same as I had before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your PersonManagerAssignment table has a person_id and a manager_id and associations in the model like has_one :person and has_one :manager. If that's the case, I'll recommend changing this association

```
has_one :person
```

to this

```
has_one :subordinate, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "person_id"
```

and then your has_many :subordinates should work as expected.

Comment: I added your changes to the original description but to not avail.

Comment: The has_many :subordinates in the Person class seems to only toggle between the Person self and the Person's manager, but not people for whom the Person's self is assigned as manager.

Comment: The join model has `belongs_to` relationships with the models it intersects

Comment: Ah, you're right. Okay, let me re-think this and edit my question if I don't figure it out from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates :through => :person_manager_assignments
  has_many :managers,    :through => :person_manager_assignments
end

class PersonManagerAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subordinate, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :manager,     :class_name => 'Person'
end
```

Comment: This is basically what I have but then Person.subordinates returns either themselves or their manager, but not the correct data, which is all the people who have the Person's self as a manager, i.e. manager_id == self.id.

Comment: I think his PersonManagerAssignment table schema requires `:foreign_key => person_id` added to the `belongs_to :subordinate` call.

Comment: I updated my question again to reflect this new information. Person.managers works, but Person.subordinates is matching the wrong value in the WHERE clause. Any ideas?

Comment: you shouldn't need `:foreign_key => person_id` as that's inferable from class_name => 'Person'

Comment: I don't think I have :foreign_key => person_id anywhere.